# Why is the build folder of my react app empty?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, production-environment

I am using create react app to make a react project.It is running without any problem on the localhost.However When  I try to build it for production.The build takes like 5 minutes and  then the build folder returned is completely empty.
I should say this now that the assets  folder inside the app is like 50mb .So dont know if thats causing the issue.If anyone has any idea what might be the problem I will appreciate it.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "dependencies": {
    "@amraneze/react-instagram-login": "^3.0.3",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "@mui/material": "^5.6.3",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "puppeteer": "^14.1.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.1",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.7.1",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: No error...it just stops .takes like a minute...when i go to the build folder there are the public files only no other files.

Comment: @MORÈ  No error...it just stops .takes like a minute...when i go to the build folder there are the public files only no other files

Comment: Are you using custom Webpack config? If so do share.

Comment: @MORÈ nope just the default create-react-app